# how to request date and location in snapchat ads api?

Tags: python, api, snapchat

i'm trying to request in snapchat ads api the result of a campaign by date (for example yesterday) and sorted by the country.

I find the request for the date

```
"https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/campaigns/["id"]/stats?granularity=DAY&start_time=["date_start"]&end_time=["date_end"]
```

And the request for the country

```
"https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/campaigns/["id"]/stats?granularity=LIFETIME&dimension=GEO&pivots=country"
```

this is my code i'm just requesting by country

```
r = requests.get("https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/organizations/" + organization_id + "/adaccounts", headers = data)

#get all the add accounts
ad_list = json.loads(r.text)
ad_list = ad_list["adaccounts"]
account_list = {}
for obj in ad_list:
    test = obj["adaccount"]
    account_list[test["name"]] = {}
    account_list[test["name"]]["id"] = test["id"]
    account_list[test["name"]]["timezone"] = test["timezone"]

#get all the add accounts campaign's
for key in account_list:
    r = requests.get("https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/adaccounts/" + account_list[key]["id"] + "/campaigns", headers = data)
    ad_id = json.loads(r.text)
    ad_id = ad_id["campaigns"]

    for obj in ad_id:
        test = obj["campaign"]
        account_list[key][test["name"]] = {}
        account_list[key][test["name"]]["type"] = "campaign"
        account_list[key][test["name"]]["id"] = test["id"]

        #get campaign stats by country
        try:
            if (req == "1"):
                r = requests.get("https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/campaigns/" + test["id"] + "/stats?granularity=LIFETIME&dimension=GEO&pivots=country&fields=impressions,swipes,spend", headers = data)
                stat = json.loads(r.text)
                stat = stat["lifetime_stats"]
                stat = stat[0]["lifetime_stat"]
                dic = stat["dimension_stats"]
                for country in dic:
                    account_list[key][test["name"]][country["country"]] = {}
                    for key2 in country:
                        account_list[key][test["name"]][country["country"]][key2] = country[key2]
        except:
              continue
```

But whatever i'm trying i can't find a way to request the country's result between two date. Is there a solution for this problem? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: could you post what have you tried till now. just giving the API url won't help.

Comment: Can you paste your code here also?

Comment: i did sorry this is my first time ^^